# Formatting a tag using CSS

Tags: css, background-image

I have the below code

```css
.adhoc-sort-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: medium;
}

.adhoc-sort-arrow-top {
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAGCAYAAAGN9z9QAAAATklEQVQI12NgQAKZIIIZiP8D8V5kGbDIfxhHBcr5wIAGMtEF3kJVqsAEdiGZ9R9qGwpwAuKfQPwHysYA/EB8A80UEL4NlQODyVgUoONpAKCTHdQ696ExAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') no-repeat left 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="adhoc-media-col-3">
  <a class="adhoc-sort-arrow adhoc-sort-arrow-top">File Name</a>
</div>
```

The issue is that I want the background arrow to appear right next to the text inside the a tag which is File Name. How can I position it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the `background-position` if the text will always be the same (font-size, font-family, etc) and you cannot change the html:

```css
.adhoc-sort-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: medium;
}

.adhoc-sort-arrow-top {
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAGCAYAAAGN9z9QAAAATklEQVQI12NgQAKZIIIZiP8D8V5kGbDIfxhHBcr5wIAGMtEF3kJVqsAEdiGZ9R9qGwpwAuKfQPwHysYA/EB8A80UEL4NlQODyVgUoONpAKCTHdQ696ExAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') 
  calc(50% - 45px) 50%/10px no-repeat;
/*calc(50% + 45px) to make it on the right*/
}
```

```html
<div class="adhoc-media-col-3">
  <a class="adhoc-sort-arrow adhoc-sort-arrow-top">File Name</a>
</div>
```

Or you can adjust the code like this by introducing a `span` tag in case the text will be dynamic

```css
.adhoc-sort-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: medium;
}

.adhoc-sort-arrow-top span{
  padding:0 15px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAGCAYAAAGN9z9QAAAATklEQVQI12NgQAKZIIIZiP8D8V5kGbDIfxhHBcr5wIAGMtEF3kJVqsAEdiGZ9R9qGwpwAuKfQPwHysYA/EB8A80UEL4NlQODyVgUoONpAKCTHdQ696ExAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') 
  left/10px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="adhoc-media-col-3">
  <a class="adhoc-sort-arrow adhoc-sort-arrow-top"><span>File Name</span></a>
</div>
<div class="adhoc-media-col-3">
  <a class="adhoc-sort-arrow adhoc-sort-arrow-top"><span>File Naaaame</span></a>
</div>
<div class="adhoc-media-col-3">
  <a class="adhoc-sort-arrow adhoc-sort-arrow-top"><span>File</span></a>
</div>
```